# UI Technology options are missing in Cross-Platform template

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

Project > Visual C# > Cross-Platform > Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpiiF.jpg). The form that appears after hitting "OK" does not provide UI Technology options: (Xamarin Forms/Native) like it used to.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been logged on the Visual Studio developer community forum: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/215468/ui-technology-options-are-missing-in-cross-platfor.html

In the meantime, if you are looking to develop a new Xamarin solution using Xamarin native instead of Xamarin.Forms, you can do this by creating each platform app individually, and then creating your shared project or class library all within one solution.

For Android native: Project > Visual C# > Android > Blank App (Android)

For iOS: Project > Visual C# > iOS > Universal > Blank App (iOS)

If you're using a class library to host your shared code, remember to add a reference to the class library in both the Android and iOS projects.